# Montmorency Island, Québéc?

Tags: canada, place-names

I have lots of records that allegedly come from churches in “Montmorency I., Québec, Canada.”  I had assumed that the ‘I’ was for Île (Island).  But I cannot find such a place in Canada—not even a historical mention online.  And it seems that at least two of the churches are on the mainland, with the nearest island being Île d’Orleans.  There is a Montmorency Falls nearby, but that’s “chutes de montmorency” in French.  A few sources omit the ‘I’, and one says “No 1” (surely incorrectly).

Wikipedia gives some former names for Île d’Orleans but none of them are Montmorency.

Is there something else the ‘I’ could mean?  (Maybe I should be looking for a French language stack.)

Comment: What time period are your records from? Sometimes place names change over time.

Comment: They are from early French Canada, but as I said, none of the historical names I’ve found for the _island_ include the word Montmorency.

Comment: In french the world "île" comes *before* the name of the island, not after like in English.

Comment: @Bregalad, as a Spanish speaker, I should have thought of that.  On the other hand, I’m looking at indexes created by people who may have thought it worthwhile to change things.  (I once volunteered to do indexing for FamilySearch.org but quit in disgust when _they_ demanded that  I falsify certain things instead of demanding that their programmers not be lazy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a numeral 1 (one) in the original, easily misinterpreted by transcribers/indexers as a lowercase letter l (ell) or a capital letter I (eye).

The FamilySearch [catalog for Quebec](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=100&placeId=305&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Canada%2C%20Qu%C3%A9bec%22) lists "Montmorency No 1" and "Montmorency No 2" as places within Quebec:

[image: Places within Quebec]

According to the FamilySearch wiki for [Montmorency No 1](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Montmorency_No_1_County,_Quebec_Genealogy):

> The Montmorency County No. 1, originally called First division Montmorency County , was a municipal county of Quebec that existed between 1855 and 23 September 1981. The area where he is now included in the administrative region of Capitale-Nationale and corresponded to the entire current regional county municipality (RCM) of the Côte-de-Beaupré plus a small part of that of Jacques-Cartier . Its capital was the municipality of Château-Richer.

Contrast this with [Montmorency No 2](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Montmorency_No_2_County,_Quebec_Genealogy):

> The County of Montmorency No. 2 , originally called Second Division Montmorency County, was a municipal county of Quebec that existed between 1855 and 1 st January 1982 . The area where he is now included in the administrative region of Capitale-Nationale and corresponded to the current regional county municipality (RCM) of Île d'Orléans . Its capital was the municipality of Sainte-Famille.

Comment: Maybe it _should_ have been a '1' but it has definitely been recorded as 'I' in many places.

Comment: It was probably handwritten as an ambiguous vertical line that was interpreted and transcribed and/or indexed as a capital I.